# How to call a method when a link is clicked in Java Servlet

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I'm implementing a web application written in Java working on the Apache Tomcat server (6.0.4).

What I currently want to do is calling a method when the following link is clicked.

```
response.getWriter().println("<a href=\"./NextPage\">Next</a>");
```

For JavaScript, `onClick` works, however it seems no to work for Java.

Do you have any tips?

===More details===

I'm implementing Java servlet for a web application.

Once a link is clicked, a user goes to the next servlet.

Before moving to the next servlet (once a link is clicked), the program should call a method which registers some input values by a user to a database.

I would not like to use JavaScript.

Comment: Can you give a little more background about your project and some snippets?

Comment: well, onClick works because your browser comes with a Javascript engine embedded. Java is a completely different story. You want it to work in the client or in the server side?

Comment: @Leo : It should work in the server side.

Comment: @ Dakota Brown : I have just edited...

Comment: `response.getWriter().println(...)` welcome to 1997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a form in the following way:

(I am assuming we are starting from scratch)

A. define your servlet in your web.xml file under Web-Inf:

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>cs336.servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
<servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

B. In your .jsp page, you need to somehow point to this servlet on action, you do it in the following way:

```
<form class="LoginHeader" method="POST" action="Login">
    <span>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="User Name / Email" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br>
        <span id="loginError"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="buttonWhite" id="loginButton"> <br>
        <input type="submit" id="forgotPassword" value="I forgot my password...">   
    </span>  
    <a id="createAccount" href="index.html">Register</a>
</form>
```

C. In your servlet, you need to handle this event with the proper method, in this case:

```
protected void doPost(  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException { ... }
```

This is as much I can tell you with the little background you gave. Pretty much, you have to do a POST to call the servlet, intercept it with the servlet method, do what you have to do, and then you could:

```
response.sendRedirect(...)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a servlet or use a struts framework or something like that.

If you use jsp you might be able to call another jsp page that calls a java function.

```
<a href=\"./NextPage.jsp\">Next</a>
```

NextPage.jsp:

```
<%
somejavafunction();
%>
```